# Creating new data with user input in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

```
#Directory change
import os
os.chdir('D:\\Scripts\\Visual Studio Code\\money_outflow')
print('Current directory:', os.getcwd())

#Importing pandas as pd
import pandas as pd 

#Reading account.csv
accountData = pd.read_csv("account.csv")
print(accountData.head())

#User input
date = input('Enter today''s date: ')
amount = (input('Enter the amount: '))

#Appending input
user_input = pd.DataFrame({'Date': [date],
                           'Amount Spent': [amount]})
user_input.to_csv('account.csv', mode='a', index=False, header=False)

#Statistics
accountData['Mean'] = accountData['Amount'].mean()
accountData['Rolling Mean 10'] = accountData['Amount'].rolling(10).mean()
accountData['Rolling Mean 30'] = accountData['Amount'].rolling(30).mean()

print(accountData.tail())
```

Hi! I am trying to create a program that calculates general and rolling mean of amounts of money spent.
The code runs fine until it hits the #Statistics part, it tells me there is a key error.
Any idea how it can be fixed?
The CSV file data looks like this:

```
       Date  Amount Spent  Mean  Rolling Mean 10   Rolling Mean 30
0  7/8/2021             0   NaN              NaN               NaN
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `accountData['Mean'] = accountData['Amount'].mean()` There is no `Amount` column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

accountData['Rolling Mean 10'] = accountData['Amount Spent'].rolling(10).mean()

Use Amount spent instead of Amount above
This may help

Comment: Omggg Thank you a lot

Comment: It's my pleasure 